# windows form not closing when message box is yes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

This is my code:

```
Private Sub frmName_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to logout?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then                   
            Me.Close()
        Else
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If I click `no` it will cancel the form closing, but when I click `yes` the message box will appear repeatedly. What i want to happen is when I click the close button, and clicked `yes` it will close the form. How can I fix this?

Comment: The irony is, if `MessageBox.Show` was not blocking you'd be experiencing a `*StackOverflow*Exception`... Markus'es answer is right, `Me.Close` invokes the `FormClosing` event so remove that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Form is already closing, there is no need to call `Close()` again. The following code should work:

```
Private Sub frmName_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to logout?", _
                "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then                   
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```